# Searching database multiple cells

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database

I have a search bar on my homepage where users can enter info and if it matches a tag it will show the service linked to that tag (example: search for support and it will show a link to the IT Support page)

Each tag is stored in a database in a separate cell with a unique id that links to a chosen service. This works great until the user enters two tags in the same search bar which returns no results.

```
$action = (isset($_POST['action'])) ? $_POST['action'] : '';
$searchTerm = (isset($_POST['search_term'])) ? $_POST['search_term'] : '';

if($searchTerm != "" && $action == "service-search"){

$query = $modx->newQuery('Service');
$query->select($modx->getSelectColumns('Service','Service','',array('id', 'subject', 'link', 'target')));
$query->leftJoin('ServiceTag', 'ServiceTag', 'Service.id = ServiceTag.service_id');
$query->leftJoin('Tag', 'Tag', 'Tag.tag_id = Tag.id');
$query->where(array(
    array(
        'OR:Tag.tag:LIKE' => '%' .$searchTerm. '%'
    ),
    array(
        'AND:Tag.published:=' => 1,
        'AND:Tag.deleted:=' => 0,
        'AND:Service.published:=' => 1,
        'AND:Service.deleted:=' => 0
    )
));
$query->sortby('Service.subject','ASC');
$query->limit(10);

$suggestions = $modx->getCollection('Service', $query);

if(count($suggestions) > 0){
    foreach($suggestions as $suggestion) {

        $listItems[] = array(
        "label"=>$suggestion->get('subject'),
        "link"=>$suggestion->get('link'),
        "target"=>$suggestion->get('target')
        );
    }

}else{
    $listItems[] = array(
    "label"=>"no results found",
    "link"=>"/services",
    "target"=>""
    );      
}
return json_encode($listItems);
```

}

I have this block of PHP and I believe it is the line

```
'OR:Tag.tag:LIKE' => '%' .$searchTerm. '%'
```

That needs altering, to handle multiple $searchTerms. I have been trying to get this working for the past few days with no luck! any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Hi Andy which wrapper are you using for mysql, can't you just do a split via whitespace for your parameters and then add another AND to your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is more than one word in $searchTerm you have to split those and add a LIKE statement for each of them.

Assumed there is "foo bar" in $searchTerm,
you check: WHERE tag LIKE "%foo bar%" but there is no tag "foo bar".

you have to check: 
    WHERE (tag LIKE "%foo%" OR tag LIKE "%bar%")

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchTermSplit = $searchTerm;
$pieces = explode(" ", $searchTermSplit);
$wordOne = $pieces[0];
$wordTwo = $pieces[1];
```

Along with

```
'WHERE:Tag.tag:LIKE' => '%' .$searchTerm. '%',
'OR:Tag.tag:LIKE' => '%' .$wordOne. '%' .$wordTwo. '%'
```

This seems to work well, thank you everyone :)